# How to add setSelection method logic to custom listview in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have developed a custom 3D ListView by following this [tutorial](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/). I am able to create the `listview` successfully. However, now I wish to scroll down and up in the listview by using Button events. I have created following functions for scrolling down and up in the `listview`.

```
    //scroll list down
public void scrollListDown(){
    int count = 20;
    int currentSelected = mListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
    if (currentSelected != (count -1) && currentSelected < (count - 1)) {
        int count1 = currentSelected + 1;   
        mListView.setSelection(count1);         
    }   
}
```

However, in this example, they have not written any implementation for the `setSelection` method. Due to this the scrolling does not work. I wish to move the selection from one item to another when a button is clicked. My function works on a normal `ListView` in Android

Currently, I have written a logic for the setSelection method as follows:

```
@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!isInTouchMode()) {
        position = lookForSelectablePosition(position, true);
        if (position >= 0) {
            setNextSelectedPositionInt(position);
        }
    } else {
        mResurrectToPosition = position;
    }

    if (position >= 0) {
        mLayoutMode = LAYOUT_SPECIFIC;
        mSpecificTop = 10;

        if (mNeedSync) {
            mSyncPosition = position;
            mSyncRowId = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
        }

        requestLayout();
    }

}
```

This is not working as expected. Can anyone suggest how I should use the `setSelection` method in this case?

My Adapter class

```
    /**
 * A simple list view that displays the items as 3D blocks
 */
public class MyListView extends AdapterView<ListAdapter> {

/** Width of the items compared to the width of the list */
private static final float ITEM_WIDTH = 0.85f;

/** Space occupied by the item relative to the height of the item */
private static final float ITEM_VERTICAL_SPACE = 1.45f;

/** Ambient light intensity */
private static final int AMBIENT_LIGHT = 55;

/** Diffuse light intensity */
private static final int DIFFUSE_LIGHT = 200;

/** Specular light intensity */
private static final float SPECULAR_LIGHT = 70;

/** Shininess constant */
private static final float SHININESS = 200;

/** The max intensity of the light */
private static final int MAX_INTENSITY = 0xFF;

/** Amount of down scaling */
private static final float SCALE_DOWN_FACTOR = 0.15f;

/** Amount to rotate during one screen length */
private static final int DEGREES_PER_SCREEN = 270;

/** Represents an invalid child index */
private static final int INVALID_INDEX = -1;

/** Distance to drag before we intercept touch events */
private static final int TOUCH_SCROLL_THRESHOLD = 10;

/** Children added with this layout mode will be added below the last child */
private static final int LAYOUT_MODE_BELOW = 0;

/** Children added with this layout mode will be added above the first child */
private static final int LAYOUT_MODE_ABOVE = 1;

/** User is not touching the list */
private static final int TOUCH_STATE_RESTING = 0;

/** User is touching the list and right now it's still a "click" */
private static final int TOUCH_STATE_CLICK = 1;

/** User is scrolling the list */
private static final int TOUCH_STATE_SCROLL = 2;

/** The adapter with all the data */
private ListAdapter mAdapter;

/** Current touch state */
private int mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_RESTING;

/** X-coordinate of the down event */
private int mTouchStartX;

/** Y-coordinate of the down event */
private int mTouchStartY;

/**
 * The top of the first item when the touch down event was received
 */
private int mListTopStart;

/** The current top of the first item */
private int mListTop;

/**
 * The offset from the top of the currently first visible item to the top of
 * the first item
 */
private int mListTopOffset;

/** Current rotation */
private int mListRotation;

/** The adaptor position of the first visible item */
private int mFirstItemPosition;

/** The adaptor position of the last visible item */
private int mLastItemPosition;

/** A list of cached (re-usable) item views */
private final LinkedList<View> mCachedItemViews = new LinkedList<View>();

/** Used to check for long press actions */
private Runnable mLongPressRunnable;

/** Reusable rect */
private Rect mRect;

/** Camera used for 3D transformations */
private Camera mCamera;

/** Re-usable matrix for canvas transformations */
private Matrix mMatrix;

/** Paint object to draw with */
private Paint mPaint;

/** true if rotation of the items is enabled */
private boolean mRotationEnabled = true;

/** true if lighting of the items is enabled */
private boolean mLightEnabled = true;


int mSyncPosition;
long mSyncRowId = INVALID_ROW_ID;
long mNextSelectedRowId;
boolean mNeedSync = false;
int mLayoutHeight;
private boolean mAreAllItemsSelectable = true;
private int mResurrectToPosition;
private int mLayoutMode, mSpecificTop,mNextSelectedPosition;
static final int SYNC_SELECTED_POSITION = 0;
int mSyncMode;
static final int LAYOUT_SPECIFIC = 4;


/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param context The context
 * @param attrs Attributes
 */
public MyListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    mAdapter = adapter;
    removeAllViewsInLayout();
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
public ListAdapter getAdapter() {
    return mAdapter;
}

@Override
public void setSelection(int position) {
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!isInTouchMode()) {
        position = lookForSelectablePosition(position, true);
        if (position >= 0) {
            setNextSelectedPositionInt(position);
        }
    } else {
        mResurrectToPosition = position;
    }

    if (position >= 0) {
        mLayoutMode = LAYOUT_SPECIFIC;
        mSpecificTop = 10;

        if (mNeedSync) {
            mSyncPosition = position;
            mSyncRowId = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
        }

        requestLayout();
    }

}

public void setNextSelectedPositionInt(int position) {
    mNextSelectedPosition = position;
    mNextSelectedRowId = getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    // If we are trying to sync to the selection, update that too
    if (mNeedSync && mSyncMode == SYNC_SELECTED_POSITION && position >= 0) {
        mSyncPosition = position;
        mSyncRowId = mNextSelectedRowId;
    }
}

/**
 * Find a position that can be selected (i.e., is not a separator).
 *
 * @param position The starting position to look at.
 * @param lookDown Whether to look down for other positions.
 * @return The next selectable position starting at position and then searching either up or
 *         down. Returns {@link #INVALID_POSITION} if nothing can be found.
 */
public int lookForSelectablePosition(int position, boolean lookDown) {
    final ListAdapter adapter = mAdapter;
    if (adapter == null || isInTouchMode()) {
        return INVALID_POSITION;
    }

    final int count = adapter.getCount();
    if (!mAreAllItemsSelectable) {
        if (lookDown) {
            position = Math.max(0, position);
            while (position < count && !adapter.isEnabled(position)) {
                position++;
            }
        } else {
            position = Math.min(position, count - 1);
            while (position >= 0 && !adapter.isEnabled(position)) {
                position--;
            }
        }

        if (position < 0 || position >= count) {
            return INVALID_POSITION;
        }
        return position;
    } else {
        if (position < 0 || position >= count) {
            return INVALID_POSITION;
        }
        return position;
    }
}



/* @Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
}*/

/**
 * Enables and disables individual rotation of the items.
 * 
 * @param enable If rotation should be enabled or not
 */
public void enableRotation(final boolean enable) {
    mRotationEnabled = enable;
    if (!mRotationEnabled) {
        mListRotation = 0;
    }
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Checks whether rotation is enabled
 * 
 * @return true if rotation is enabled
 */
public boolean isRotationEnabled() {
    return mRotationEnabled;
}

/**
 * Enables and disables lighting of the items.
 * 
 * @param enable If lighting should be enabled or not
 */
public void enableLight(final boolean enable) {
    mLightEnabled = enable;
    if (!mLightEnabled) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(null);
    } else {
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
    }
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Checks whether lighting is enabled
 * 
 * @return true if rotation is enabled
 */
public boolean isLightEnabled() {
    return mLightEnabled;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startTouch(event);
        return false;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        return startScrollIfNeeded(event);

    default:
        endTouch();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startTouch(event);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_CLICK) {
            startScrollIfNeeded(event);
        }
        if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_SCROLL) {
            scrollList((int)event.getY() - mTouchStartY);
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_CLICK) {
            clickChildAt((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
        }
        endTouch();
        break;

    default:
        endTouch();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(final boolean changed, final int left, final int top, final int right,
        final int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    // if we don't have an adapter, we don't need to do anything
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        mLastItemPosition = -1;
        fillListDown(mListTop, 0);
    } else {
        final int offset = mListTop + mListTopOffset - getChildTop(getChildAt(0));
        removeNonVisibleViews(offset);
        fillList(offset);
    }

    positionItems();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean drawChild(final Canvas canvas, final View child, final long drawingTime) {
    // get the bitmap
    final Bitmap bitmap = child.getDrawingCache();
    if (bitmap == null) {
        // if the is null for some reason, default to the standard
        // drawChild implementation
        return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }

    // get top left coordinates
    final int top = child.getTop();
    final int left = child.getLeft();

    // get centerX and centerY
    final int childWidth = child.getWidth();
    final int childHeight = child.getHeight();
    final int centerX = childWidth / 2;
    final int centerY = childHeight / 2;

    // get scale
    final float halfHeight = getHeight() / 2;
    final float distFromCenter = (top + centerY - halfHeight) / halfHeight;
    final float scale = (float)(1 - SCALE_DOWN_FACTOR * (1 - Math.cos(distFromCenter)));

    // get rotation
    float childRotation = mListRotation - 20 * distFromCenter;
    childRotation %= 90;
    if (childRotation < 0) {
        childRotation += 90;
    }

    // draw the item
    if (childRotation < 45) {
        drawFace(canvas, bitmap, top, left, centerX, centerY, scale, childRotation - 90);
        drawFace(canvas, bitmap, top, left, centerX, centerY, scale, childRotation);
    } else {
        drawFace(canvas, bitmap, top, left, centerX, centerY, scale, childRotation);
        drawFace(canvas, bitmap, top, left, centerX, centerY, scale, childRotation - 90);
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Draws a face of the 3D block
 * 
 * @param canvas The canvas to draw on
 * @param view A bitmap of the view to draw
 * @param top Top placement of the view
 * @param left Left placement of the view
 * @param centerX Center x-coordinate of the view
 * @param centerY Center y-coordinate of the view
 * @param scale The scale to draw the view in
 * @param rotation The rotation of the view
 */
private void drawFace(final Canvas canvas, final Bitmap view, final int top, final int left,
        final int centerX, final int centerY, final float scale, final float rotation) {

    // create the camera if we haven't before
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    // save the camera state
    mCamera.save();

    // translate and then rotate the camera
    mCamera.translate(0, 0, centerY);
    mCamera.rotateX(rotation);
    mCamera.translate(0, 0, -centerY);

    // create the matrix if we haven't before
    if (mMatrix == null) {
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
    }

    // get the matrix from the camera and then restore the camera
    mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
    mCamera.restore();

    // translate and scale the matrix
    mMatrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    mMatrix.postTranslate(left + centerX, top + centerY);

    // create and initialize the paint object
    if (mPaint == null) {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }

    // set the light
    if (mLightEnabled) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(calculateLight(rotation));
    } else {
        mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF - (int)(2 * Math.abs(rotation)));
    }

    // draw the bitmap
    canvas.drawBitmap(view, mMatrix, mPaint);
}

/**
 * Calculates the lighting of the item based on rotation.
 * 
 * @param rotation The rotation of the item
 * @return A color filter to use
 */
private LightingColorFilter calculateLight(final float rotation) {
    final double cosRotation = Math.cos(Math.PI * rotation / 180);
    int intensity = AMBIENT_LIGHT + (int)(DIFFUSE_LIGHT * cosRotation);
    int highlightIntensity = (int)(SPECULAR_LIGHT * Math.pow(cosRotation, SHININESS));

    if (intensity > MAX_INTENSITY) {
        intensity = MAX_INTENSITY;
    }
    if (highlightIntensity > MAX_INTENSITY) {
        highlightIntensity = MAX_INTENSITY;
    }

    final int light = Color.rgb(intensity, intensity, intensity);
    final int highlight = Color.rgb(highlightIntensity, highlightIntensity, highlightIntensity);

    return new LightingColorFilter(light, highlight);
}

/**
 * Sets and initializes all things that need to when we start a touch
 * gesture.
 * 
 * @param event The down event
 */
private void startTouch(final MotionEvent event) {
    // save the start place
    mTouchStartX = (int)event.getX();
    mTouchStartY = (int)event.getY();
    mListTopStart = getChildTop(getChildAt(0)) - mListTopOffset;

    // start checking for a long press
    startLongPressCheck();

    // we don't know if it's a click or a scroll yet, but until we know
    // assume it's a click
    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_CLICK;
}

/**
 * Resets and recycles all things that need to when we end a touch gesture
 */
private void endTouch() {
    // remove any existing check for longpress
    removeCallbacks(mLongPressRunnable);

    // reset touch state
    mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_RESTING;
}

/**
 * Scrolls the list. Takes care of updating rotation (if enabled) and
 * snapping
 * 
 * @param scrolledDistance The distance to scroll
 */
public void scrollList(final int scrolledDistance) {
    mListTop = mListTopStart + scrolledDistance;
    //mRotationEnabled = false; 
    if (mRotationEnabled) {
        mListRotation = -(DEGREES_PER_SCREEN * mListTop) / getHeight();
    }
    requestLayout();
}

public void scrollListViewUp(final int scrolledDistance) {
    mListTop = mListTopStart + scrolledDistance;
    //mRotationEnabled = false; 
    if (mRotationEnabled) {
        mListRotation = -(DEGREES_PER_SCREEN * mListTop) / getHeight();
    }
    requestLayout();
}

public void scrollListViewDown(final int scrolledDistance) {
    mListTop = mListTopStart + scrolledDistance;
    //mRotationEnabled = false;
    if (mRotationEnabled) {
        mListRotation = -(DEGREES_PER_SCREEN * mListTop) / getHeight();
    }
    requestLayout();
}


/**
 * Posts (and creates if necessary) a runnable that will when executed call
 * the long click listener
 */
private void startLongPressCheck() {
    // create the runnable if we haven't already
    if (mLongPressRunnable == null) {
        mLongPressRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mTouchState == TOUCH_STATE_CLICK) {
                    final int index = getContainingChildIndex(mTouchStartX, mTouchStartY);
                    if (index != INVALID_INDEX) {
                        longClickChild(index);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // then post it with a delay
    postDelayed(mLongPressRunnable, ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout());
}

/**
 * Checks if the user has moved far enough for this to be a scroll and if
 * so, sets the list in scroll mode
 * 
 * @param event The (move) event
 * @return true if scroll was started, false otherwise
 */
public boolean startScrollIfNeeded(final MotionEvent event) {
    final int xPos = (int)event.getX();
    final int yPos = (int)event.getY();
    if (xPos < mTouchStartX - TOUCH_SCROLL_THRESHOLD
            || xPos > mTouchStartX + TOUCH_SCROLL_THRESHOLD
            || yPos < mTouchStartY - TOUCH_SCROLL_THRESHOLD
            || yPos > mTouchStartY + TOUCH_SCROLL_THRESHOLD) {
        // we've moved far enough for this to be a scroll
        removeCallbacks(mLongPressRunnable);
        mTouchState = TOUCH_STATE_SCROLL;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Returns the index of the child that contains the coordinates given.
 * 
 * @param x X-coordinate
 * @param y Y-coordinate
 * @return The index of the child that contains the coordinates. If no child
 *         is found then it returns INVALID_INDEX
 */
private int getContainingChildIndex(final int x, final int y) {
    if (mRect == null) {
        mRect = new Rect();
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++) {
        getChildAt(index).getHitRect(mRect);
        if (mRect.contains(x, y)) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return INVALID_INDEX;
}

/**
 * Calls the item click listener for the child with at the specified
 * coordinates
 * 
 * @param x The x-coordinate
 * @param y The y-coordinate
 */
private void clickChildAt(final int x, final int y) {
    final int index = getContainingChildIndex(x, y);
    if (index != INVALID_INDEX) {
        final View itemView = getChildAt(index);
        final int position = mFirstItemPosition + index;
        final long id = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
        performItemClick(itemView, position, id);
    }
}

/**
 * Calls the item long click listener for the child with the specified index
 * 
 * @param index Child index
 */
private void longClickChild(final int index) {
    final View itemView = getChildAt(index);
    final int position = mFirstItemPosition + index;
    final long id = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
    final OnItemLongClickListener listener = getOnItemLongClickListener();
    if (listener != null) {
        listener.onItemLongClick(this, itemView, position, id);
    }
}

/**
 * Removes view that are outside of the visible part of the list. Will not
 * remove all views.
 * 
 * @param offset Offset of the visible area
 */
private void removeNonVisibleViews(final int offset) {
    // We need to keep close track of the child count in this function. We
    // should never remove all the views, because if we do, we loose track
    // of were we are.
    int childCount = getChildCount();

    // if we are not at the bottom of the list and have more than one child
    if (mLastItemPosition != mAdapter.getCount() - 1 && childCount > 1) {
        // check if we should remove any views in the top
        View firstChild = getChildAt(0);
        while (firstChild != null && getChildBottom(firstChild) + offset < 0) {
            // remove the top view
            removeViewInLayout(firstChild);
            childCount--;
            mCachedItemViews.addLast(firstChild);
            mFirstItemPosition++;

            // update the list offset (since we've removed the top child)
            mListTopOffset += getChildHeight(firstChild);

            // Continue to check the next child only if we have more than
            // one child left
            if (childCount > 1) {
                firstChild = getChildAt(0);
            } else {
                firstChild = null;
            }
        }
    }

    // if we are not at the top of the list and have more than one child
    if (mFirstItemPosition != 0 && childCount > 1) {
        // check if we should remove any views in the bottom
        View lastChild = getChildAt(childCount - 1);
        while (lastChild != null && getChildTop(lastChild) + offset > getHeight()) {
            // remove the bottom view
            removeViewInLayout(lastChild);
            childCount--;
            mCachedItemViews.addLast(lastChild);
            mLastItemPosition--;

            // Continue to check the next child only if we have more than
            // one child left
            if (childCount > 1) {
                lastChild = getChildAt(childCount - 1);
            } else {
                lastChild = null;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Fills the list with child-views
 * 
 * @param offset Offset of the visible area
 */
private void fillList(final int offset) {
    final int bottomEdge = getChildBottom(getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1));
    fillListDown(bottomEdge, offset);

    final int topEdge = getChildTop(getChildAt(0));
    fillListUp(topEdge, offset);
}

/**
 * Starts at the bottom and adds children until we've passed the list bottom
 * 
 * @param bottomEdge The bottom edge of the currently last child
 * @param offset Offset of the visible area
 */
private void fillListDown(int bottomEdge, final int offset) {
    while (bottomEdge + offset < getHeight() && mLastItemPosition < mAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
        mLastItemPosition++;
        final View newBottomchild = mAdapter.getView(mLastItemPosition, getCachedView(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(newBottomchild, LAYOUT_MODE_BELOW);
        bottomEdge += getChildHeight(newBottomchild);
    }
}

/**
 * Starts at the top and adds children until we've passed the list top
 * 
 * @param topEdge The top edge of the currently first child
 * @param offset Offset of the visible area
 */
private void fillListUp(int topEdge, final int offset) {
    while (topEdge + offset > 0 && mFirstItemPosition > 0) {
        mFirstItemPosition--;
        final View newTopCild = mAdapter.getView(mFirstItemPosition, getCachedView(), this);
        addAndMeasureChild(newTopCild, LAYOUT_MODE_ABOVE);
        final int childHeight = getChildHeight(newTopCild);
        topEdge -= childHeight;

        // update the list offset (since we added a view at the top)
        mListTopOffset -= childHeight;
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a view as a child view and takes care of measuring it
 * 
 * @param child The view to add
 * @param layoutMode Either LAYOUT_MODE_ABOVE or LAYOUT_MODE_BELOW
 */
private void addAndMeasureChild(final View child, final int layoutMode) {
    LayoutParams params = child.getLayoutParams();
    if (params == null) {
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
    final int index = layoutMode == LAYOUT_MODE_ABOVE ? 0 : -1;
    child.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    addViewInLayout(child, index, params, true);

    final int itemWidth = (int)(getWidth() * ITEM_WIDTH);
    child.measure(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY | itemWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
}

/**
 * Positions the children at the "correct" positions
 */
private void positionItems() {
    int top = mListTop + mListTopOffset;

    for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++) {
        final View child = getChildAt(index);

        final int width = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        final int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        final int left = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
        final int margin = getChildMargin(child);
        final int childTop = top + margin;

        child.layout(left, childTop, left + width, childTop + height);
        top += height + 2 * margin;
    }
}

/**
 * Checks if there is a cached view that can be used
 * 
 * @return A cached view or, if none was found, null
 */
private View getCachedView() {
    if (mCachedItemViews.size() != 0) {
        return mCachedItemViews.removeFirst();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Returns the margin of the child view taking into account the
 * ITEM_VERTICAL_SPACE
 * 
 * @param child The child view
 * @return The margin of the child view
 */
private int getChildMargin(final View child) {
    return (int)(child.getMeasuredHeight() * (ITEM_VERTICAL_SPACE - 1) / 2);
}

/**
 * Returns the top placement of the child view taking into account the
 * ITEM_VERTICAL_SPACE
 * 
 * @param child The child view
 * @return The top placement of the child view
 */
private int getChildTop(final View child) {
    return child.getTop() - getChildMargin(child);
}

/**
 * Returns the bottom placement of the child view taking into account the
 * ITEM_VERTICAL_SPACE
 * 
 * @param child The child view
 * @return The bottom placement of the child view
 */
private int getChildBottom(final View child) {
    return child.getBottom() + getChildMargin(child);
}

/**
 * Returns the height of the child view taking into account the
 * ITEM_VERTICAL_SPACE
 * 
 * @param child The child view
 * @return The height of the child view
 */
private int getChildHeight(final View child) {
    return child.getMeasuredHeight() + 2 * getChildMargin(child);
}

@Override
public View getSelectedView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```